# mouse wheel event for horizontal and vertical scrolling lags in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mousewheel

I'm trying to make horizontal scroll on a div when the user scrolls both horizontally or vertically.

Here's my code :

```
const scroller = document.getElementById('scroller')

window.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    // Gives priority to the higher value between horizontal or vertical scroll 
    if (Math.abs(e.deltaY) > Math.abs(e.deltaX)) {
        scroller.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
    }
    else {
        scroller.scrollLeft += e.deltaX;
    }
})
```

This code works well in chrome but it lags in Firefox on horizontal scrolling.

The delta values are different in chrome and in firefox and I can't help to work it nicely in firefox.

How can I normalize this code in this browsers ?